# Can anyone explain what is meant by <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>?

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am trying to setup ElasticSearch OpenDistro but I am not able to understand what is meant by `<CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>` in the link

https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/community/blob/master/open-distro-elasticsearch-kubernetes/elasticsearch/35-es-bootstrap-secrets.yml .

How should I use this yaml file? Do I need to put the base64 encoded values here replacing the  and then `kubectl apply -f secrets.yaml` or what?

Can someone provide any reference link around this which explains the same?

`````
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-tls-data
  namespace: elasticsearch
type: Opaque
stringData:
  elk-crt.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>
  elk-key.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>
  elk-root-ca.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>
  admin-crt.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>
  admin-key.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED>
  admin-root-ca.pem: |-
    <CERTIFICATE_DATA_REDACTED> ````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this configuration before, but on my opinion what you should do is create your own certificates `elk-crt.pem, elk-key.pem, elk-root-ca.pem, admin-crt.pem, admin-key.pem, admin-root-ca.pem` same thing with Kibana (if you will use it), then just create your Secret with raw values,

please read this:

`For certain scenarios, you may wish to use the stringData field instead. This field allows you to put a non-base64 encoded string directly into the Secret, and the string will be encoded for you when the Secret is created or updated.`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/